# Does stress affect the urinary pH?

Tags: stress, uric-acid

I've read a [few](https://www.urmc.rochester.edu/encyclopedia/content.aspx?contenttypeid=85&contentid=P00053) [websites](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2684327/) which say that stress can cause buildup of uric acid. Would that make a urine test (uric acid/pH) taken after stress less accurate?

Comment: Can you link to a few sources that say that?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?